# How to check method return value calling from html template?

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, string-interpolation

Is it possible to call a method & get return value from html template inside the double curly braces.
e.g.  {{method-name}}?

Ans:- yes.

But i'm not able to compare the return value, how do it?

**My use case is via calling the method passing some arguments and doing some operation & returning**

[Please look into stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aevjxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: with what you want to compare? and what is the code you have tried for comparing?

Comment: Actually i returning bool type values. But not able compare? in template showing correctly.

Comment: where you are comparing? I don't see any code in the question related to comparison, can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: Sure , Thanks @Pardeep

Comment: stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aevjxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want an *ngIf if Im looking at the stackblitz.

```
<p *ngIf="compareFun(message.a , message.b)">true</p>
```

Calling a function from the html is a bad idea and I dont recommend it. Since you want to display the returned value of the function when the function returns true, it can be hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks @ukn, but want to display actual compareFun return value after compare.

Comment: @Alam You said: I want to display the <p> when the value is true, so just hardcode true. It just doesnt make sense tho, why would you display true but never false?

Comment: Nice @ukn for function calling recommended, thanks once again